# How to fix this HDB issue caused by fixtable ran on HDB with symlinks

Tags: kdb

Tried to fix an hdb partition using fixtables without realising that there are some symlinks in there.

Now when I query that table I get the following error:

```
"./2016.05.18/:./2016.05.18/tablename. OS reports: No such file or directory"
```

Any suggestions?

UPDATE: I don't think the fixtable caused this. I thing the following line caused it

```
(hsym`$getenv`hdb)set .Q.en[hsym`$getenv`hdb;]table
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like from your error that a partition has been placed within itself. Does the following directory exist?

```
q) key `:./2016.05.18/:./2016.05.18
```

If so then the issue is that a partition has been placed within itself.

If that error message is a typo or a red herring then you should first cover your basis and fill the HDB. For the HDB at `/some/hdb/location`

```
.Q.chk[`:/some/hdb/location]
```

If that doesn't work then the table might exist but be broken. So inspect it and see if it's queryable

```
tabCheck: get `:./2016.05.18/tablename
```

If the table is queryable, then check that the schema conforms with the rest of the HDB.